# Simpler Singleton Based on Jon Skeet's Singleton

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I need a singleton in my code.  I read Jon Skeet's [page](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on Singletons and selected this model (#4) based on his recommendation:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton(){}

    private Singleton(){}

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I then went through a few steps to modify this to fit my scenario:

**Step 1:** I don't need a lazy implementation, so I took out the static constructor (as suggested by Jon at the end of his article):

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton(){}

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** I then swapped out the "instance" `Singleton` class with the `Logging` class I am working with :

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Logging instance = new Logging();

    private Singleton(){}

    public static Logging Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Resharper then told me that I should use an auto property for my "Instance" property:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private Singleton(){}

    public static Logging Instance { get; } = new Logging();
}
```

**Step 4:** Resharper then told me I should switch this to a static class:

```
public static class Singleton
{
    public static Logging Instance { get; } = new Logging();
}
```

What I am left with is very different from the original. I know that it is very easy to get things wrong when setting up a thread safe Singleton.

So I wanted to ask: **Do any of my steps make my class not a good Singleton implementation any more?**

Comment: This is not Singleton implementation at all. What you created is just shared static variable of **another** type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do any of my steps make my class not a good Singleton implementation any more?

Yes, they do.

The behavior you removed in Step #1 is an implementation detail anyway. Removing the empty static constructor is fine; if you want to force lazy init, `Lazy<T>` is a better way anyway even if it has slightly more overhead.

At Step #2, your object stopped being a singleton at all, because you no longer have control over how many instances of the object (`Logging`) are created.

I'd say that not being a singleton at all qualifies as being "not a good Singleton implementation".

Comment: I think what I am looking for is not a simple Singleton then.  I may have to post another question in a bit.  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Incase anyone is interested, I posted my follow up question to this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42259505/16241