# Implementing a "Singleton" like feature using internal

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I am creating a NuGet package for my company that will surface a logger for applications to use.

I want my logger to function similar to a Singleton (only one instance and thread safe).

Here is what I have:

```
public sealed class Log
{
    public static ILogger Logger { get; } = new Logger();
}

internal sealed class Logger: ILogger
{
     // Do Stuff Here
}
```

The classes will be in my NuGet assembly, so the consumers will not be able to modify them.

**So if someone calls `Log.Logger` is it thread safe?  And single instance?**

Comment: I don't understand this version of your question. Singletons are not themselves inherently thread-safe. Only the _property_ that returns the singleton instance is, using the normal, thread-safe patterns for singleton. The code above is neither a singleton (per our discussion in your previous question...there's nothing to stop someone from calling `new Logger()` directly), nor does it magically make the `Logger` class itself thread-safe (even though the `Log.Logger` property is).

Comment: Jon Skeet (StackOverflow's numero uno) has extensively covered the Singleton pattern, if this is any help? http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @PeterDuniho They can call `new Logger()` even though it is `internal` and in an assembly they cannot modify?  I guess I don't understand `internal` then :(

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I am only looking for the `Log.Logger` to be thread safe.  As you said, I will have to (and plan on) dealing with the thread safety of the `Logger` class myself.

Comment: @series0ne -  Believe it or not, but I based this on that.  Here is the question that got me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258375/simpler-singleton-based-on-jon-skeets-singleton

Comment: _"They can call new Logger() even though it is internal"_ -- a true singleton, cannot be created by _any_ other class, even those in the same assembly. Use of `internal` can give you some singleton-like protection against outside code, but it's not really making the type a singleton.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - fair enough.  I agree that in it does not fit the definition of a Singleton.